# Could not find the correct provider above this MyApp widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use a provider in `MaterialApp`. I have a `MultiProvider` which is a parent of the `MaterialApp`.

When I try accessing the provider, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<RoutesProvider>(create: (context) => RoutesProvider()),
        ...
      ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'coolApp',
          // key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false).mainKey,
          initialRoute: '/home',
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{...routes},
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below structure, `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` is the right way of assigning provider

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: RoutesProvider()),
        //.....
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
```

Comment: @Jessica: It seems you are old SO user, then why you don't upvote the answers which helped you. It's a good practice by the way, not specific to my answer only.